# How can I "store" the last result of a PRNG in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, random, mutable

For an assignment I have to write a pseudorandom number generator in Haskell. I'm not sure how it's possible in Haskell to "remember" the last value returned by the function, since that's required by the definition of a pseudorandom number generator (the next number in the sequence is based on the last number returned).

In an imperative language I could just keep a global variable or something:

```
int last_rand;

int myRandom()
{
   last_rand =  (some operation on last_rand);
   return last_rand;
}
```

But in Haskell, or at least, from what I know of Haskell, there's no way to store and update a mutable record of values returned by a function... how can I go about this?

Comment: Check out record types. Also you may want to look into how [System.Random](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.0.2/docs/System-Random.html)'s functions work.

Comment: You need a monad for this.

Comment: Why not just not to pass `last_rand` explicitly into `myRandom`? You don't even need state other than the result itself, so just stream it through function calls and reuse `last_rand` for recursive calls.

Comment: @EarlGray that's forbidden by the assignment specification, unfortuntaely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to recommend you to read [Chapter 9 Input and Output - Randomness](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#randomness) and [Chapter 13 For a Few Monads More - Making monads](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#making-monads) (lookup for Tasteful stageful computations section) of [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com) book.

There you would find solution (or keys for solution) of your assignment.

P. S. I give links to book, because there is no sense in copy-pasting it's content. Just straight links :)